# How to show button checking a localStorage key with Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

When I log out I delete the token. Here is how I check if the token is deleted:

```
  const isLoggedOut = () => {
    let token = window.localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token === undefined || token === null || token.length === 0) {
      console.log("user is logged out")
      return true
    }
    else {
      console.log("user is logged in")
      return false
    }
  }
```

Inside the navbar I want the Login button to be hidden if the user is logged in.
This is how the navbar looks like:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <router-link class="navbar-brand" :to="{ name: 'Home' }">Home</router-link>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link class="text-white" :to="{ name: 'Login' }" v-if="isLoggedOut">Login</router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link class="text-white ml-2" :to="{ name: 'Register' }">Register</router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link class="text-white ml-2" :to="{ name: 'Dashboard' }">Dashboard</router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <button class="text-white ml-2" @click="logOut">Logout</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

*Later edit*, this is the App.vue file without the styles. I log in and Login button still appears in the navbar.

```
<script setup>
  import { reactive,ref, computed } from 'vue'
  import { useRouter } from "vue-router"

  const router = useRouter()

  const token = ref(null);
  const setToken = (token) => {
    token.value = token;
    window.localStorage.setItem('token', token)
  } 
  const clearToken = () => {
    token.value = null;
    window.localStorage.removeItem('token')
  }

  const isLoggedOut = computed(() => token.value === null)

  const logOut = () => {
    clearToken()
    router.push({name:'Login'})
  }

</script>

<template>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <router-link class="navbar-brand" :to="{ name: 'Home' }">Home</router-link>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">

        <!-- Show Login button only if user is logged out -->
        <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link class="text-white" :to="{ name: 'Login' }" v-if="isLoggedOut">Login</router-link>
        </li>
        
        <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link class="text-white ml-2" :to="{ name: 'Register' }">Register</router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link class="text-white ml-2" :to="{ name: 'Dashboard' }">Dashboard</router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button class="text-white ml-2" @click="logOut">Logout</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <router-view/>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is still visible because the component (`App.vue` in your case) is not reloaded, meaning the check whether you have a token or not is not performed, respectively the computed is not going to be updated because as mentioned above `window.localStorage` is not reactive.

One way to overcome this is to use a store (pinia/vuex/composable that will hold the value all the time) and router hooks, like `beforeRouteEnter` or the global one - `beforeEach`.

You can also try to make `localStorage`reactive like in this example [here](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-make-localstorage-reactive-in-vue/)

Which might be overkill.

Just make sure you moved token functions and operations in a separated file (or even as a composable)

Answer (score 4):

`window.localStorage.getItem('token')` is not reactive. If the value changes, you will not be notified.

Instead of getting logged in state from localStorage, you can manage it through internal state which will then manage the local storage.

for example:

```js
const token = ref(null);
const setToken = (value) => {
  token.value = value;
  window.localStorage.setItem('token', token)
} 
const clearToken = () => {
  token.value = null;
  window.localStorage.removeItem('token')
}
const isLoggedIn = computed(()=>token.value !== null)
```

then you can use `isLoggedIn` as a reactive (computed) value.

You can store this in a separate `auth.js` and export the methods and token.

[example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNq1VM2OmzAQfpWpLxApgNRjSqJW6qErVarU7ZGLAUO8MTayTbIV4t072EDYrLrpoXvCZvz9zIw9PfnStvG5Y2RHUlNo3lowzHbtIZMAvGmVttCDZrSw/My2mlVbKFTTdpaVMEClVQMB4oNMjohCSWPBqhOTsEdYFcpOiM2nawzZf03h8ExFxzawP0A/HgAPjN1vjLuvgwJcuCzVJRaqoOLRKk1rFiPVg2VNGDhYsPXwzQgY4KpYCEb1ovl3udHpG2qaNerM1oJeaZ04N99VXbPyR2eRcK5T6EVfqO29HlJc0ULVHvjC5NV+6AQBtEJWHbedOYa9pA3bBSjLZTBcHaWJ7yb2ETdouhXUMtfVVNIzslJj9hnBdU41+E/Enlsqy8g0kNdRSfVpDozrjDg4EuSdtUrecES5RmxGYGcV/uwRis4g+KYaFqApchhXaeLBM1Unbmnw45T8AXfoQxTB41FdwKUJk7yS4jfwCjrDNFZ+LB+WHrA4EEUTv4MLvtaIOFYDbeKiwj+rli0JLsibRC17ttHliASv0/QdGPOEz4XgxQmD4WZ/mO97GBhMf7445ODO31TDaSaCr7b30vhnx9CI6ONr2z9ZzQ3eJt+heXff1/u4+UrNMVdUl97Osv0vfu67WRrnX6LvEt6nt+XTpBP+YSWo7Fauzbu+nybhMKS5TvxIna7bg9wBxtcDY8CHmybLUyVb4udv1NA2fjJK4ox2MwEvrQuYjCCJN5ERHMLjPiNHa1uzSxJTFeNkfzKx0nWCq1h30vKGxcw0+FrVBR8OEmdkmhoDGf4A7o71rQ==)

Comment: It doesn't work either, I updated the question.

Comment: I've had a mistake in the code, `token` was the name of the passed variable which broke in `token.value = token` I've updated and added  example link

Comment: Looking on my code I set token inside Login component (on click I go there with :to RouterLinkProp). This way doesn't work.

Comment: I made it work using Pinia, thanks for your help!